# Світильник чи люстра?

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Не раз чув як на світильник кажуть люстра. Вирішив дізнатися чи є різниця між цими двома словами. Пошуки в Інтернеті не дали ніяких результатів. В СУМі знайшов цих два слова.

**[Люстра](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljustra)**:

> Підвісний освітлювальний прилад, що має кілька джерел світла (свічок,
>   електроламп) і оздоблену арматуру.

**[Світильник](http://sum.in.ua/s/svityljnyk)** має декілька значень, однак одне із них:

> Великий освітлювальний прилад, а також арматура до нього.

Не був впевнений, що на основі цього можна вважати "люстру" та "світильник" взаємозамінними, тому вирішив ще пошукати інформацію в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), але серед запропонованих синонімів до слова "світильник" немає "люстри".

Цікаво чи можуть ці слова інколи заміняти одне одного чи ні? І яка між ними різниця?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слово ***світильник*** — це фактично **синонім до словосполучення *освітлювальний прилад***. Принаймні так вважає Вікіпедія (там стаття «Освітлювальний прилад» є просто перенаправленням на «Світильник»). Щоправда, Вікіпедія не підтверджує це джерелами, але по-моєму, це було б доволі логічно, враховуючи спосіб творення цього слова.

**Люстра — різновид світильника**. Щоправда різні джерела дають різні трішки тлумачення:

- [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljustra) (поданий Вами же):

  > Підвісний освітлювальний прилад, що має кілька джерел світла (свічок, електроламп) і оздоблену арматуру

  Отже: (1) підвісний; (2) має кілька джерел світла; (3) має оздоблену арматуру.
- [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48793&page=1538) (новіший):

  > Підвісний освітлювальний прилад, що має **перев[ажно]** кілька джерел світла (свічок, електроламп) та оздоблену арматуру

  А тепер мати кілька джерел світла вже необов'язково (лише «переважно» має).
- [Українська Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0) (без джерел, [станом на 21 листопада 2018](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0&oldid=23819540)):

  > підвісний освітлювальний прилад на декілька джерел світла з декоративно оформленою арматурою для **загального** освітлення приміщень

  Отже тут це для загального освітлення приміщень; якщо підвісити маленький оздоблений світильник на декілька ламп над столом (що освітлює лише стіл, а не все приміщення загалом) — то це вже буде не люстра.

  Хоча тлумачення для російського *люстра* й англійського *chandelier* не зобов'язані збігатися з тлумаченням для українського *люстра* (ці слова цілком можуть мати дещо різні значення), але для повноти наведу приклади тлумачень з іншомовних Вікіпедій:

  - [Російська](//ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0&oldid=97862543):

    > підвісний світильник **для стелі**, призначений для створення **безтіньового** освітлення (на відміну від точкових джерел) приміщень

    А тут уже нема нічого про декілька джерел, оздоблення чи загальне освітлення, зате зазначено безтіньове освітлення.
  - [Англійська](//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chandelier&oldid=868011956):

    > розгалужений [з декількох гілок] декоративний освітлювальний прилад, призначений для монтажу на стелю чи стіни

    Тут трішки змінюються акценти: не написано, що люстра сама має бути оздобленою (ornamented), а написано, що люстра оздоблює приміщення (в моєму перекладі — декоративна, в оригіналі — ornamental); окрім того її можна вішати не лише на стелю, а й на стіни (власне, навіть сказано не «вішати», а «монтувати» — це ширше слово).
- І т. ін.

Отже, якщо підсумувати: люстру найчастіше вішають (хоча за деякими тлумаченнями — можуть монтувати іншим чином), причому найчастіше на стелю (хоча за деякими тлумаченнями — можна деінде, зокрема на стіну); найчастіше вона оздоблена (чи то призначена оздоблювати приміщення); найчастіше має гіллясту форму й уміщує декілька джерел світла; найчастіше вона призначена створювати загальне (а не локалізоване) безтіньове (а не точкове) освітлення.